# Line is not drawn

Tags: android, android-canvas, java-canvas

I want to draw a dashed line from point A to point B

Here is my code:

but the path is never drawn

```
paintDotted = new Paint();
paintDotted.setAntiAlias(true);
paintDotted.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paintDotted.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
paintCircle.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(20));
paintDotted.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
paintDotted.setStrokeWidth(4);

Path dottedPath = new Path();
dottedPath.moveTo(avgStartX, avgEndY);
dottedPath.lineTo(avgEndX,avgEndY);
Log.i("avgStartX",avgStartX+"");
Log.i("avgStartY",avgStartY+"");
Log.i("avgEndY",avgEndY+"");
Log.i("avgEndX",avgEndX+"");
canvas.drawPath(dottedPath, paintDotted);
```

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the start and end values sane (give samples)?  Where does canvas come from?  Is it a screen canvas or a bitmap canvas?  Is this the onDraw function or elsewhere?

Comment: No the start and end values are different, and this code is called from the onDraw method of a linear layout

Answer (score 0):

The problem should come from the fact that you are using a `Style.FILL` on a 1 dimensional element (a line with no height). You have to use `Style.STROKE` instead.

BTW, if you just want to display a line you should use this:

```
drawLine(float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY, Paint paint)
```

from the `Canvas` class. 
Note that the `startY` and `stopY` must be different. This draw will be 2 dimensional and you will be able to use `Style.FILL`.